# Java regular expression matching for CSS double class attribute

Tags: java, css, regex

I'd like to have a boolean that tells me if a CSS selector has either:

- Id selector (#) + Class selector (.) in the same element, such as table#someid.someclass
- Class selector (.) + Id selector (#) in the same element, such as table.someclass#someid
- Double class selector (.) in the same element, such as table.class1.class2

The substring has to be matched in a selector that might include combinators such as table > tr#someid.someclass > td...

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MultipleClassId {
private static final String regexs[] = {
        "(#[^\\s\\+>~\\.\\[:]+)(\\.[^\\s\\+>~\\.\\[:]+)",
        "(\\.[^\\s\\+>~\\.\\[:]+)(#[^\\s\\+>~\\.\\[:]+)",
        "(\\.[^\\s\\+>~\\.\\[:]+)(\\.[^\\s\\+>~\\.\\[:]+)" };

public boolean isMultipleClassId(String selector) {
    for (int i = 0; i < regexs.length; i++) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexs[i]);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(selector);
        if (m.find())
            return true;
    }
    return false;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter selector: ");
    String selector = input.next();
    MultipleClassId specificityCalculator = new MultipleClassId();
    boolean isMultiple = specificityCalculator.isMultipleClassId(selector);

    System.out.println(isMultiple);
}

}
```

It finds the pattern if the first element of the selector has the multiple attribute selector, such as "tr#someid.someclass", and for any of the cases listed above. However, if I have a selector such as "table tr#someid.someclass" it returns false.

Nevertheless, in RegexPlanet, it matches it correctly (check the following link http://fiddle.re/ykedp).

Is it a problem of my Java libraries version? Or there is something wrong in my code?
Thanks!

Comment: can you provide some sample input data for testing?

Comment: I think you just need to prepend and append `.*` to your regexes to have them match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was just the

```
String selector = input.next();
```

that had to be replaced with

```
String selector = input.nextLine();
```